# How can a charged insulator produce an electric discharge?

Tags: electrostatics, electrons

Wouldn't you need a conductor for the electrons to be able to flow from one object to another?

[Additional Info]
If a metal object with excess electrons comes into contact with a neutral metal object, electric charges will flow until both objects have the same charge.

When an insulating charged object ( e.g. PVC ) comes into contact with a neutral metal object, how can the electrons move through the PVC to the point where it is in contact with the metal object?

I would expect the amount of charge transferred to be extremely small compared to metal objects, possibly too small to detect using simple experiments, but this is clearly not so.

Comment: The insulator becomes conducting if it reaches the breakdown voltage.

Comment: I would also add that there is no perfect insulator. Everything conducts electricity, even empty space.

Comment: This question seems somewhat unclear: What is the charged insulator? What is is supposed to discharge to? A charged woollen jumper can partially discharge to my (conducting) hand when I touch charged parts, a charged cloud can discharge through the air in lightning if the voltage is large enough, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you charge an insulator in air with a large enough surface charge, the electric field at the surface can easily exceed the breakdown field of air leading to ionization of air molecules and a discharge current. This causes frequently observed spark discharges after frictional contact of different (insulating) materials, especially when the air humidity is low.. See [Triboelectric Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect).